# How can I NOT serialize some part (subobject) of an Object using JAX-RS interface?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jackson2

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("b")
    B b;
    // constructors, getters, etc.
}

class B {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Integer id

    // other properties ...

    @JsonProperty("c")
    C c;

    // getters and setters
}

class C {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Integer id

    // other properties ...

    @JsonProperty("password")
    String password;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I "own" class A in my project, by classes B and C comes from another project (JAR dependency included in DOM). I collect information of B by calling a REST interface. Along with B, comes C, which contains a password in it.

When I send A to the user, all objects are serialized. This way, C (and the password) goes along.

How can I send A with B, but omit C?

I can't change B and C:

1. I can't put @JsonIgnore on C in class B;
2. There is not setter in B, so i can't a.getB().setC(null).

Here comes the real question:
1. Is there any annotation I can put in my REST interface (I use RESTEasy) so that Jackson can serialize without the C class?

2. Or, if not, how could I do that by coding?

I would not like to create another object "B-like" and copy all the properties. There should be a better way (I hope).

Comment: I would recommend to build your own object with just the Info you want to send and serialize this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation on "b":

```
class A {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("b")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"c"})
    B b;
    // constructors, getters, etc.
}
```

I hope it helps you.